# How can I optimize Objectify relationships?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I'm building an application with Google App Engine. I'm using Objectify for Datastore persistence. I have two POJO class.

```
@Entity
public class Book
{
    @Id private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String isbn;
    private String author;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id private String email;
    private String password;
    private String name;
    private List<Book> myBooks;
}
```

A person can contain many books but book only belongs to one person. Currently I'm saving data like this.

```
//data from Front-end
Person p = new Person(email, password, name);
PersonDAO dao = new PersonDAO();
dao.save(p);

//...
//data from Front-end
Book b = new Book(name, author, isbn);
BookDAO daoBook = new BookDAO();
daoBook.save(b);

//...
Person q = dao.load(email);
q.addBook(b);
dao.save(q);
```

ObjectifyService ofy() with methods are implemented in DAO classes.

It's ok my implementation? How can I optimize the relationship? Every time that I need create a book this is saved like Entity but I need the relationship with a person, therefore I'm saving book twice. I've seen implementantions with Key, Ref @Load tags but I don't know how are working them.

Besides, Person POJO has a Date field. will It be saved normally?

Answer (score 0):

It has being quite a while since I wrote this code, but here it goes:

```
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Parent
    @ApiResourceProperty(ignored = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)
    private Key<User> user;

    private String author;

    private String isbn;

    private String name;

}
```

Take a look at [Udacity Conference Central](https://github.com/jpventura/conference-central-android-app/blob/naosei/backend/src/main/java/com/google/devrel/training/conference/domain/Session.java) for full example. It is the final project of [Developing Scalable Apps in Java
with Google App Engine](https://udacity.com/course/developing-scalable-apps-in-java--ud859), by [Udacity](https://udacity.com/).

Comment: That code can work for identify owner's book but if I want to looking for books that have one person I would need to search in every book. However, thanks a lot. Actually, I'm developing an android application and your example code and udacity mooc can be useful for me.

Comment: This is how you establish a 1-to-many relationship between `User` and `Book`. You can also create indexes for searching by specific fields, such as `user`. Do not forget that you need to created the indexes at Google App Engine and that they are paid.

Comment: Please, update your question description to include field search.